# How install pygame to pythonista apps

Tags: python, pygame, pythonista

I am trying to install pygame in the pythonista app.

I installed Stash, but when I tried `pip install pygame` an error appeared like 'Cannot locate packages.Manual installation required'

Why do I get this error and how can I install pygame library to the pythonista app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pygame relies on C code that is not installable on Pythonista.